# How to read & display ID3 tags while playing shoutcast streaming with Adobe AIR?

Tags: javascript, streaming, air, shoutcast

How to read & display ID3 tags while playing shoutcast streaming with Adobe AIR + JavaScript (**without using external Flex/Flash players**) ?

Comment: How you do this depends entirely on what you are using to get the stream.  The metadata is embedded directly into the MP3 stream, every 8192 bytes (or whatever is specified by the icy-metaint header from the server).  Furthermore, when requesting the stream, the client must specify icy-metadata:1 in the header.  There is some excellent documentation on this here:  http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html   If you are unable to pull the meta out of the stream client-side, then you can also do this server side.  I've written some PHP that can do it.

Comment: I am using: new air.Sound() to play shoutcast streams
Using server side solutions to read metadata is undesirable.
I’d like to keep my application completely client-side (Adobe AIR + JavaScript), but very curious about PHP code you’ve written.